# jquery: How to find within prevUntil

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I got the following selection when i used prevUntil

[image]

This object is stored in a var `ttt`

Now i am trying

```
$(ttt).find("strong")
```

It does not return any strong element

The images shows the output

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible .. because here `ttt` will have array of elements .. as you can see op i.e :`0,1..`

Comment: As you see its not w.r.t array. Its something to do with `selector: ".prevUntil(span) strong'` . Eg. I check for `$('div').find('p').find('strong')` It works there the selector is `div p strong`. And also its looks like an object with keys as numbers.

Comment: Hi , you can use `siblings` instead of `find` . Here is [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/j435znx8/2/)

Comment: that works thank you. But why is find not working.